# c# следующий за курсором объект

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу реализовать следующую идею: При нажатии кнопки пикчер бокс начинает следовать за курсором со скоростью, заданной таймером (допусим timertick=50). Как это правильно реализовать? Я знаю, как получить текущие координаты курсора:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    point1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

Понимаю, как заставить пикчербокс двигаться:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox5.Location = new Point(pictureBox5.Location.X + a, pictureBox5.Location.Y + b); // смещает координаты пикчербокса на a пикселей по оси X и на b по оси Y
}
```

Подскажите как реализовать движение за курсором, то есть каждый тик таймера пикчербокс должен двигаться в сторону текущего положения курсора.
Код по ответу:

```
Point point1;
Point point2;
Point point3;
private void Form4_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{         
   point1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   point2 = pictureBox5.Location;
   point3 = new Point(point1.X - point2.X, point1.Y - point2.Y);
   pictureBox5.Location = point3;
}
```

Comment: проект winforms? вижу в тегах только c#

Comment: Да, в winforms. Добавил тег, спасибо!

Comment: @Алексей, задавайте вопросы, если мой ответ непонятен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала задайтесь вектором направления движения. Конечная точка минус начальная. Затем необходимо найти [единичный вектор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) заданного направления и умножить на желаемую длину шага:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Шаг
    int r = 5;
    // Вектор направления движения
    int x = point1.X - label1.Location.X;
    int y = point1.Y - label1.Location.Y;
    // Двигаться никуда не нужно, защита от деления на 0
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) return;
    // Длина вектора
    double k = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    // Вектор заданного направления с желаемой длиной
    int dx = (int)(r * x / k);
    int dy = (int)(r * y / k);
    label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + dx, label1.Location.Y + dy);
}
```

С использованием `ValueTuple` код можно написать еще более математически:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int r = 5;
    var (x, y) = (point1.X - label1.Location.X, point1.Y - label1.Location.Y);
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) return;
    double k = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    var (dx, dy) = ((int, int))(r * x / k, r * y / k);
    label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + dx, label1.Location.Y + dy);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Сейчас попробую реализовать и если будут вопросы спрошу!

Comment: Андрей, общий смысл Вашего решения я понял, но реализация у меня хромает. В моём коде (он выше) при движении мыши пикчербокс смещается в нужную сторону, но только когда мышь двигается, при её остановке останавливается и пикчербокс. Как я понимаю, я исполнил только первый Ваш шаг.

Comment: @Алексей, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь во всём разобрался.